# ADF Mobile : Too many Android emulators connected

Tags: android, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

Hello am developing my first Oracle MAF mobile application. By using [Developing ADF Mobile Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_setup/tut_jdev_maf_setup_2.html) documents I configured my JDeveloper12c for MAF, And I have created 2 emulator of different configuration. Finally when am trying to deploy my application I am getting the following error.

```
[10:28:38 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[10:28:38 PM] Target platform is  (Android).
[10:28:39 PM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "My2App" to Android using profile "MyApp2Andrd".
[10:28:40 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[10:28:44 PM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[10:28:44 PM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...
[10:28:44 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[10:28:45 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:28:45 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:28:45 PM] Too many Android emulators connected.  Only one emulator should be connected for deployment.  The following results were provided by ADB:
List of devices attached
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5554   device
 (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
```

Comment: Stop one of the emulators.

Comment: the adb is confused by 2 emulators. close one

Comment: Previously I have created many emulators. Now I have deleted all and using only one. Still the error is same. I think emulators details are stored some where.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to stop and restart the adb server.
And then just start one emulator.

Comment: Hello shay. I have restarted adb server as follows L:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

L:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

L:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>. And Now I have only one emulator. Still same error in jdeveloper. Please Help me...